# Rendering specific component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used the ScrollView's onMomentumScrollEnd handler to determine the current page based on the contentOffset in the [recyclerlistview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) Component.

```
 const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

 const onScrollEnd = (e) => {
    let contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
    let viewSize = e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;
    let pageNum = Math.floor(contentOffset.x / viewSize.width);
    setCurrentPage(pageNum);
  };

return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <RecyclerListView
          rowRenderer={({ item }, index) => <Page item={item} id={index} />}
          dataProvider={list}
          layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
          isHorizontal
          pagingEnabled
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 0.1, backgroundColor:"gold" }}>
          <Text>{`current page: ${currentPage}`}</Text>
       </View>
      </View>
  );
```

I want to display the current Page inside a Text component, but when currentPage state changes in **onMomentumScrollEnd** handler the whole app is re-render. I need to re-render only the Text Component, any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. the easiest way is to create a class component and put the displayed component in it, then I reference it and change the current page with **ref hook**.

```
 class DisplayCurrentPage extends React.Component {
   contractor(prop){
    super(prop)
    state:{currentPage:0}
   }
   updateCurrentPage = (index) => {this.setState({CurrentPage: index})}
   render(){
    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 0.1, backgroundColor:"gold" }}>
          <Text>{`current page: ${this.state.currentPage}`}</Text>
       </View>
     );

   }

 };
  

 const reference = createRef();
 const onScrollEnd = (e) => {
    let contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
    let viewSize = e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;
    let pageNum = Math.floor(contentOffset.x / viewSize.width);
    reference.current.updateCurrentPage(pageNum);
  };

return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <RecyclerListView
          rowRenderer={({ item }, index) => <Page item={item} id={index} />}
          dataProvider={list}
          layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
          isHorizontal
          pagingEnabled
        />
        <DisplayCurrentPage ref={reference} />
      </View>
  );
```

When the page is changed, only **DisplayCurrentPage** is re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) which is an alternative to shouldComponentUpdate for functional components. It tells React when to re-render the component based on prev and next props.

```
const Item = React.memo(({ item }) => {  
  return (
    <View>
      ........
    </View>
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried to use React.memo but doesn't work because when the state change the whole app is re-render including recyclelistview component.